# Group bar plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have the following data in R.

```
> dat
           algo taxi.d taxi.s hanoi.d. hanoi.s     ep
1      plain VI   7.81   9.67    32.92   38.12 140.33
2      model VI  12.00  46.67    53.17  356.68 229.89
3 our algorithm   6.66   6.86    11.71   21.96 213.27
```

I have made a graph of this in Excel, now I want something similar in R. Please note that the vertical scale is logarithmic, with powers of 2.

[image: graph of data in Excel]

What R commands do I need to use to have this?

Sorry if this is a very easy question, I am a complete novice to R.

Comment: Check out the `ggplot2` package. http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/

Comment: Also, are you sure you really want to use a log-scale on the y-axis? It makes it very difficult to compare these models. And what's wrong with a table? Why do you need to plot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reshape2 and ggplot packages should help accomplish what you want:

```
dat = read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"algo taxi.d taxi.s hanoi.d hanoi.s     ep
1      'plain VI'   7.81   9.67    32.92   38.12 140.33
2      'model VI'  12.00  46.67    53.17  356.68 229.89
3 'our algorithm'   6.66   6.86    11.71   21.96 213.27")

install.packages("reshape2") # only run the first time
install.packages("ggplot2") # only run the first time
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

# convert the data into a more graph-friendly format
data2 = melt(dat, id.vars='algo', value.name='performance', variable.name='benchmark')

# graph data + bar chart + log scale
ggplot(data2) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = benchmark, y = performance, fill = algo), stat='identity', position='dodge') +
  scale_y_log10()
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code will help you up with your plot

```
  dat <- matrix(c(
                c(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25),
                c(0.05,0,0.95,0),
                c(0.4,0.1,0.1,0.4)),
                nrow=4,ncol=3,byrow=FALSE,
                dimnames=list(c("A","C","G","T"),
                              c("E","S","I"))
                )

  barplot(dat,border=FALSE,beside=TRUE,
          col=rainbow(4),ylim=c(0,1),
          legend=rownames(dat),main="Plot name",
          xlab="State",ylab="observation")
  grid()
  box()
```